# Outlook Express - How To Sort Incoming Email Automatically To Appropriate Folders?

Tags: email, email-client, outlook-express

When i have dozens of email accounts, all incoming emails arrive to Inbox which makes a mess. Is there a way to tell Outlook Express to automatically assign emails to appropriate folders chosen by me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create email rules i will attach a link that should help you out to sort them as they are recieved.

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/internet/create_outlook_express_message_rules.php